# Duplicate Insertion in DB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, checkbox, duplicate-data

I have a `GridView`with rows containing `.net checkbox`control. User would check the rows and upon clicking the button it would `insert` the `checked` rows in the table `GeneratedInvoiceBatches`

VB Code:

```
Protected Sub btnGenerate_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGenerate.Click
            Dim grItem As DataGridItem
            Dim i As Integer = 0


            For Each grItem In grdTransactions.Items

                If grItem.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Or grItem.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then

                    If CType(grItem.Cells(0).FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox).Checked = True Then

                        Utilities.InsertUnsettledBatchesForInvoice(grItem.Cells(5).Text.Trim, grItem.Cells(7).Text.Trim, grItem.Cells(11).Text.Trim)

                        i = i + 1

                    End If

                End If

            Next

            If i = 0 Then
                Response.Write("<script> alert('No selected record(s) to process!');</script>")
            Else

                Response.Write("<script> alert('Operation Successful!');</script>")
                BindDataGrid()
            End If

        End Sub
```

Stored Procedure:

```
Create proc [dbo].[spInsertUnsettledBatchesForInvoice]

@TerminalID varchar(8),
@BatchNumber int,
@SettledAmount money

as


insert into GeneratedInvoiceBatches (GenerationDate,TerminalID,BatchNumber,SettledAmount,isPayment,isHSBCFile,paymentdate)
values
(GetDate(),@TerminalID,@BatchNumber,@SettledAmount,1,1,getdate())
```

Problem is sometimes it inserts duplicate rows say once in three months. Can somebody identify the issue? Is it something to do with the checkbox control? How can I avoid this duplication?

Comment: Which value determines that the record is duplicate?

Comment: If is not something thet duplicate at any click .. than is by click-ing accidentaly twice..  same row in dgv, you can check if that exist in db an warn ..

Comment: Yes Seems like i Have to use the NOT EXISTS with subquery to check if there are duplications

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the button is being clicked twice in rapid succession. Can you uncheck the boxes inside your If-Then right after calling the DB insert? That way, the second click will find no checked boxes.